# Mounting Filesystems on unix

Tags: unix, command-line

I'm coming across a problem when I'm trying to do multiple mounts across multiple servers.

I have a server that has a file system called /etc/exports on server A

```
mount -o vers=3 1.1.1.1/export/scripts/ /export/scripts/
```

But now I want to mount from Server B to server C kind of like a middle man but I get the error:

```
exportfs: /export/scripts does not support NFS export
```

Basically I want A -> B -> C

Comment: That `mount` command can't possibly work. Are you missing a colon after `1.1.1.1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't re-export an NFS filesystem from a NFS client so that it acts as a server toward another downstream client. You'll want to mount the filesystem on host C directly from host A.

Comment: Ye i guess I will have to figure out a way to do this. I'm trying to do it because Server C is the only one with access to a certain server but hasn't got access to Server A but than thanks for input.